# Draw path is not closing the shape

Tags: php, pdflib

I'm using PDFLib v-8 and trying to generate triangle using that path point. I'm able to generate 2 sides of triangle not the complete one. Though I can add one more path to that,but in the case of uneven shape I'll be not able to do that just because of unawareness of the complete shape.

Is there any what to determine the complete shape and draw the complete path using path point in pdflib ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which functions you are using to create path and draw path ?

Comment: What kind of question that was ?
As per my knowledge, add_path_point and draw_path are the 2 functions which we can use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
PDFLib_draw_path($triangle_path, x, y, "close stroke fitmethod=entire ");
```

Here, close option will complete the shape.

Thanks.